# Jenkins drops flags for ssh command?

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh, jar, scp

I have this step in Jenkins build

[image: jenkins screenshot]

```
echo "ws is"
echo ${WORKSPACE}/build/libs/RoutingRegression-fat-1.0.jar

scp ${WORKSPACE}/build/libs/RoutingRegression-fat-1.0.jar root@${REGR_IP_ADDR}: 
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@${REGR_IP_ADDR} 
./opt/waze/bin/regression/deploy_jar.sh 1
```

but in the run console I don't see the `ssh flags` I have added

```
14:05:02 + echo 'ws is'
14:05:02 ws is
14:05:02 + echo /data/workspace/java/RoutingRegression/route_flavor_historic_time_3/ws/build/libs/RoutingRegression-fat-1.0.jar
14:05:02 /data/workspace/java/RoutingRegression/route_flavor_historic_time_3/ws/build/libs/RoutingRegression-fat-1.0.jar

14:05:02 + scp /data/workspace/java/RoutingRegression/route_flavor_historic_time_3/ws/build/libs/RoutingRegression-fat-1.0.jar root@104.155.98.131:
14:05:03 Host key verification failed.
14:05:03 lost connection
14:05:03 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: You don't have there any `scp` flags. You added the flags to the `ssh` command (it is not executed, probably because the `scp` command failed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have there any `scp` flags. You added the flags to the `ssh` command (it is not executed, probably because the previous `scp` command failed).

Add the flags to the `scp` command.

Comment: which flags I should add? I don't know why the scp fails

Comment: The same you added to the `ssh` command, the same way. I will not write them here since you pasted only image.